# tooltip on chart not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've created a line-chart in D3 (with angular) and trying to implement tooltips. The problem is, when I append the tooltip DIV to directive element, it doesn't work, while it works fine if I append the div to body (which I don't want):

```
// not working
// d3.select(element[0]).append() doesn't work either
var div = g.append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("opacity", 0);

// works fine
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("opacity", 0);
```

[Here is the JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/opajad48/) (line 69)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use HTML elements (such as `div`) inside a SVG, unless you use a foreign object (not supported by all browsers). You can create your tooltip using a `rect` element.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't knew it. :) I instead changed the template element to `<div id="chart"></div>` instead of <svg> and appended the tooltip to this div.